# How can I make one element change its width according to the line's remaining width?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Referring [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kx67L/).

html:

```
<div class="w">
    <span class="e e1">Tag</span>
    <span class="e e2">type</span>
    <span class="e e3">This is a long text, and I hope it can end with ellipsis if it's really too long</span>
    <span class="e e4">Jul 27 2014</span>
    <span class="e e5">Comment</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.w {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.e {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.e3 {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I hope all the five elements can be displayed **in the same line**. And all elements except for `e3` will show all their content. The remaining width will be allocated to `e3`. If the width is not enough for displaying all the content in `e3`, ellipsis will be displayed at the end of `e3`.

I preferring not hard code the `width` property to `e3` for line width and other element's width may change.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

change

display property of div with class 'w' to `flex`

```
.w {
 border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
}
```

for string in  span( other than one having class .e3 ) to be visible set a min-width to those span

like [Check code : by setting min-width](http://jsfiddle.net/kx67L/9/)

or you can use @media Rule ,to make your site responsive at different resolution accordingly

Comment: but, other elements will not be shown properly now.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use `flex: none` on elements `e1`, `e2`, `e3`, `e5`. refering http://jsfiddle.net/kx67L/10/

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox is the only way you are going to make this happen in just CSS, older browers like ie9 aren't going to support this. When using this make sure to use all the prefixes that are needed. The following solution should take care of everything as well as provide a solution for older browsers that isn't ideal but keeps things in one line.

```
.w {
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space:nowrap;
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex; 
}
```

Otherwise the only option is to use javascript to get the width of .w and the widths of all the .e's except .e3 and then subtract the two and use the result of that to explicitly set .e3's width.

```
$(".w").each(function(){
    //Initialize variables
    var totalWidths = 0,
        thisWidth = $(this).width(),
        e3Width = 0;
    //Loop over every E and add their width to total widths
    $(this).find(".e").not(".e3").each(function(){
        totalWidths += $(this).width();
    });
    //Calculate our final width and subtract 10 to account for borders
    e3Width = thisWidth - totalWidths - 10;
    //Set the width
    $(this).find(".e3").width(e3Width);
});
```

I've created a working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kx67L/12/) for you. As you can see I've also floated all of your elements left so they are directly next to each other. If you change your borders or margin don't forget to account for this in your javascript.

Comment: Actually, I have many those lines in sequence. like http://jsfiddle.net/kx67L/11/. Is it too difficult to implement using javascript? Could you give me some hints?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a solution for jQuery. I would have used vanilla javascript but it's a little more complicated and would need some effort to make things cross browser compatible.